# How can I query email field by comparing the date field?

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

I want the emails from contact where due_date__c is less than 15 days and 1 day.

```
Select id, email from user 
where Contact.AccountId in 
    (select Location__c from Grant_Schedule__c where Schedule_year__c = '2016'      
    and Due_date__c <= System.today() and Due_date__c <= System.today());
```

Comment: due_date__c is less than 15 days and 1 day, is there an and in between or its 16 days?

Comment: @RahulSharma I mean due_date__c is 15 days before.

Comment: Use date literals as mentioned by Baris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand if it is last 15 days or next 15 days but you can user LAST_N_DAYS:15 or NEXT_N_DAYS:15 here is the link [Salesforce Date Formats and Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)

Comment: 15  days before the due_date__c..

Comment: So it is like due_date is in next 15 days

Comment: yes..like due_date__c = 30-11-2016 then I want 15-11-2016

Comment: try due_date_c=NEXT_N_DAYS:15 . It means between today 11-11-2016 and 11-26-2015